# C# Win7 and Win2019 Convert text to image gives blur, not clear

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi, drawtext, drawstring

I have a C# programm, that convert Text to Image by using GDI+ method **Graphics.DrawString**

On my machine with Windows 7 it works good

see example image here:

[image]

[image]

But on the Windows Server 2019 it creates blurry, not clear image

see example image here:

[image]

[image]

I even tried to use GDI method **TextRenderer.DrawText**

but it gave same blur (see links above)

I tried to install .NET Framework 4.8, all Visual C++ Redistributables
but had no sucess

Comment: play with TextRenderingHint prop of Graphics

Comment: Thank you, Selvin. That is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comment of Selvin, I found the solution

on GDI TextRenderer.DrawText

```
graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

on GDI+ Graphics.DrawString

```
graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
```

Comment: With the tool "insert code" you can remove the overindenting, thus allowing better formatting.